# Reshaping data to add new columns for each value of one variable

Tags: r, dplyr

Currently I have been able to get my data looks like:

```
          date           category    revenue    cost
     20150100               1      2670935 1290161.8
     20150200               1      2487379 1201022.2
     20150300               1      2663918 1244556.4
     20150400               1      2557039 1208289.3
     20150500               1      2372128 1026402.6
     20150600               1      2981372  919436.4
     20150100               2      2670935 1290161.8
     20150200               2      2487379 1201022.2
     20150300               2      2663918 1244556.4
     20150400               2      2557039 1208289.3
     20150500               2      2372128 1026402.6
     20150600               2      2981372  919436.4
```

I want to reshape it to where it looks like the following (with additional cat2 columns):

```
          date           category  cat1.revenue    cat1.cost
     20150100               1      2670935         1290161.8
     20150200               1      2487379         1201022.2
     20150300               1      2663918         1244556.4
     20150400               1      2557039         1208289.3
     20150500               1      2372128         1026402.6
     20150600               1      2981372          919436.4
```

I do not know how to use dplyr or other data wrangling packages to get my data to look like this.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be using `gather`, `unite` and `spread` as

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% gather(key, value, -date, -category) 
 %>% unite(combined, key, category, sep = "_cat") %>%
spread(combined, value)

#      date cost_cat1 cost_cat2 revenue_cat1 revenue_cat2
#1 20150100 1290161.8 1290161.8      2670935      2670935
#2 20150200 1201022.2 1201022.2      2487379      2487379
#3 20150300 1244556.4 1244556.4      2663918      2663918
#4 20150400 1208289.3 1208289.3      2557039      2557039
#5 20150500 1026402.6 1026402.6      2372128      2372128
#6 20150600  919436.4  919436.4      2981372      2981372
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table( text = "date           category    revenue    cost
20150100               1      2670935 1290161.8
20150200               1      2487379 1201022.2
20150300               1      2663918 1244556.4
20150400               1      2557039 1208289.3
20150500               1      2372128 1026402.6
20150600               1      2981372  919436.4
20150100               2      2670935 1290161.8
20150200               2      2487379 1201022.2
20150300               2      2663918 1244556.4
20150400               2      2557039 1208289.3
20150500               2      2372128 1026402.6
20150600               2      2981372  919436.4", 
header = T, stringsAsFactor = F)
```